# React Chrome Extension not working, possible due to React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to get the React Chrome Extension working with React 13.2.  Currently, it only displays `<TopLevel></TopLevel>` instead of my components.  I think it has something to do with `React-Router` but I'm not not sure what to do to get it working.

Here is my `main.js` file:

```
require('es6-shim');

var React = require('react');
var router = require('./router');

// Expose React for the dev tools
window.React = React;

router.run((Handler, state) => {
  React.render(
    <Handler
      params={state.params}
    />,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
});
```

And the `router.js` file:

```
// Proxy calls to router to avoid circular dependencies
var router;

module.exports = {
  run(render) {
    router.run(render);
  }
};

var Router = require('react-router');
var routes = require('./routes');

router = Router.create({
  routes: routes,
  // location: Router.HistoryLocation
});
```

And the `routes.js` file:

```
var App = require('./App');
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;

var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App} />
);

module.exports = routes;
```

And then this is what I see in the React Chrome Extension:

[image]

The app itself works as expected, I just want to be able to view things using the extension.

Comment: What are the 3 warnings logged in your console? Also, what version of `react-router` are you running?

Comment: React-Router 0.13.3.  Warnings are from Immutable.js (accessing length property of an Immutable.List).

Comment: Removing [tag:google-chrome-extension], since it's not about extension development.

Comment: Have you closed Chrome dev tools and reopened? React tools only refresh the view hierarchy on re-opening. Sounds silly but caught me up the first couple of times.

Comment: I tried that.  It looks like component tree loads for a moment, then flashes and then disappears, leaving only Top Level behind.